# Secure Prometheus Server With Basic Password Authentication

Tags: prometheus, basic-authentication

I am trying to enable basic authentication to the Prometheus application. I am following the steps as per the Prometheus Documentation [https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/basic-auth/]. I have configured the web-config.xml as per the documentation.

Below is the content of web-config.xml:

basic_auth_users: 
admin: "##$#$#$#$#$#$#$"

But when I am validating the configuration, it fails and throws me the below error:

[root@Promethus-server prometheus-2.17.0-rc.0.linux-amd64]# ./promtool check config /etc/prometheus/web-config.yml
Checking /etc/prometheus/web-config.yml
FAILED: parsing YAML file /etc/prometheus/web-config.yml: yaml: unmarshal errors:
line 1: field basic_auth_users not found in type config.plain

Can someone help me on this?

Regards
Rajiv

Answer (score 1):

That seems like yaml syntax error.

as mentioned in the doc, please follow this format ( please mind the spaces in 2nd line )

```
basic_auth_users:
    admin: $2b$12$hNf2lSsxfm0.i4a.1kVpSOVyBCfIB51VRjgBUyv6kdnyTlgWj81Ay
```

> Below is the content of web-config.xml:

Hope you mean web-config.yml